# PKCS#5 padding in Swift

Tags: swift, pkcs#5

How to apply PKCS5 to an NSData ?

There doesn't seem to be much info about this yet, I've found this [Objective-C solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728947/pkcs5-padding-in-objective-c) that would work but I'm looking for a "swiftier" approach if possible.

Here is my failed attempt :

```
func pkcs5(data: NSData, blocksize: Int = 16) -> NSMutableData {
    var data = NSMutableData(data: data)
    let count = blocksize - data.length % blocksize

    for _ in 0...count {
        // somehow append the equivalent of chr(count) to data
    }

    return data
}
```

If you know Python, here's the function I'm trying to copy :

```
def pkcs5_pad(data, blocksize=16):
    pad_count = blocksize - len(data) % blocksize
    return data + (chr(pad_count) * pad_count).encode('utf-8')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `appendBytes()`:

```
func pkcs5(data: NSData, blocksize: Int = 16) -> NSMutableData {
    var data = NSMutableData(data: data)
    var count = UInt8(blocksize - data.length % blocksize)

    for _ in 0 ..< count {
        data.appendBytes(&count, length: 1)
    }

    return data
}
```

The "trick" is to declare `count` as a *variable* of type `UInt8`, so that you 
can pass a pointer with `&count`.

Alternatively, you can create an array with the padding bytes first and then
append the data in one step:

```
func pkcs5(data: NSData, blocksize: Int = 16) -> NSData {
    var data = NSMutableData(data: data)
    let count = blocksize - data.length % blocksize
    let padding = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: UInt8(count))
    data.appendBytes(padding, length: count)
    return data
}
```

Comment: @AndréDaniel: I have added another version that looks a bit Swiftier. But I doubt that it makes any difference in performance, so it is mainly a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Also I included your suggestion about `0..<count` directly in the code you provided so that someone who copy/pastes without paying attention (that's me!) doesn't copy broken code; I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think @MartinR answer is no problem, but if you want more example:

Using `libc`: performance

```
func pkcs5_mem(data: NSData, blocksize: Int = 16) -> NSData {
    let count = blocksize - data.length % blocksize
    let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(malloc(UInt(data.length + count)))
    // you should check `buf` is not `nil` here
    memcpy(buf, data.bytes, UInt(data.length))
    memset(buf + data.length, Int32(count), UInt(count))
    return NSData(bytesNoCopy: buf, length: data.length + count)
}
```

Using `NSMutableData`: safe any easy

```
func pkcs5_mutable(data: NSData, blocksize: Int = 16) -> NSData {
    let count = blocksize - data.length % blocksize
    let result = NSMutableData(capacity: data.length + count)!
    result.appendBytes(data.bytes, length: data.length)
    result.appendBytes([UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: UInt8(count)), length: count)
    return result
}
```

Using `Array` as buffer: maybe slow

```
func pkcs5_array(data: NSData, blocksize: Int = 16) -> NSData {
    let count = blocksize - data.length % blocksize
    var buf = [UInt8]()
    buf.reserveCapacity(data.length + count)
    buf += UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), count: data.length)
    buf += [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: UInt8(count))
    return NSData(bytes: buf, length: buf.count)
}
```

Comment: I made some performance tests: Your pkcs5_mem function has about the same speed as my first function, and is three times faster than  pkcs5_mutable which has about the same speed as my second function (which is no wonder because they are almost equal). pkcs5_array is even slower.